# MyBatis: recursion while mapping more than one association/collection of the same type

Tags: java, recursion, mapping, mybatis, ibatis

I've faced with one interesting problem in MyBatis, which leads to recursion while trying to map two collections of objects that are the same type.

**Introduction.**

Here is my db schema:
[simple_db_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eph2.png)

I have a simple class ***User***:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Employee employee;
    // Constructors, setters and getters go here...
}
```

Then I have class ***Employee***:

```
public class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String lastName;
    private User user;
    // Constructors, setters and getters go here...
}
```

And ***Project***:

```
public class Project {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> observers;
    private List<Employee> executors;
    // Constructors, setters and getters go here...
}
```

***Mappings***

Here I show my mappings for this schema.

**UserMapping**

```
<resultMap type="User" id="userMap">
    <id property="id" column="user_id"/>
    <result property="name" column="user_login" />
    <result property="password" column="user_password" />
    <association property="employee" javaType="org.project.entity.Employee" resultMap="Employee.employeeMap"/>
</resultMap>
```

**EmployeeMapping**

```
<resultMap id="employeeMap" type="Employee">
    <id property="id" column="emp_id" />
    <result property="lastName" column="emp_last_name" />
    <association property="user" javaType="org.project.entity.User" resultMap="User.userMap"/>
</resultMap>
```

**ProjectMapping**

```
<resultMap type="Project" id="projectMap">
    <id property="id" column="project_id" />
    <result property="name" column="project_name" />
    <collection property="managers" columnPrefix="obsrv" ofType="Employee" 
                javaType="java.util.ArrayList" resultMap="employeeMap" />
    <collection property="executors" columnPrefix="exec" ofType="Employee" 
                javaType="java.util.ArrayList" resultMap="employeeMap" />
</resultMap>
```

Note that I use "*columnPrefix*" in ProjectMapping. One is for observers and the other for executors. These collections use the same "*resultMap*" - "*employeeMap*".

**Problem.**

With this approach my mapping does not work.
There's no problem with mapping *User* in *Employee* and vice versa - that works fine.

The query to DB is correct.

I've tried different ways to sort this out (I put all mappings in one file, I removed *Employee* association in *UserMapping*) but nevertheless nothing helped.

I found one solution, but it's not exactly what I was looking for.

One way is to duplicate *UserMapping* and *EmployeeMapping* and change its IDs, and than to use it like that:

```
<resultMap type="Project" id="projectMap">
    <id property="id" column="project_id" />
    <result property="name" column="project_name" />
    <collection property="managers" columnPrefix="obsrv" ofType="Employee" 
                javaType="java.util.ArrayList" resultMap="employeeMap" />
    <collection property="executors" columnPrefix="exec" ofType="Employee"
                javaType="java.util.ArrayList" resultMap="employeeMap1" />
</resultMap>
```

It means that I have 2 copies of *UserMapping* and *EmployeeMapping* with following IDs: *userMap*, *userMap1* and *employeeMap*, *employeeMap1*.

**Question**

Please, could anybody explain me this situation? Why must I duplicate mappings? Or, probably, I've missed some settings.

I don't want to duplicate my mappings, because I want to reuse them.

Is there a solutions without duplicating these mappings?

Comment: I have the same problem. Two associations use the same resultMap definition. That seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, some days ago I faced the same problem again and I've solved it.

The answer is so simple: do not forget to write correct equals & hashCode for your domains.

The reason of my problem was absence of equals & hashCode methods (or they were incorrect), that's why mybatis couldn't resolve which object should go to collection #1 or #2.

So, if anyone is interested in some details, let me know and I'll provide some samples.